# How to make a 2D array to a Gomoku chess board

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I need to convert this 2D array to a gomoku chess board
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stHjJ.png)
like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GAcp.png)
“--” and “|” should be used to represent the grid of the board.
And 0 in the array representing the blank spot, 1 representing black stone was placed, -1 representing white stone was placed. I also need to show how the stones were placed.

```
import numpy as np
def create_board(size):
    boardSize = size
    ChessLen = 50
    global board_matrix
    board_matrix = np.zeros((boardSize,boardSize),dtype=int)
    for i in board_matrix:
        print("--".join(' ' for j in range(boardSize)))
        print(" |".join(' ' for j in range(boardSize-1)))
    print(board_matrix)
create_board(9)
```

This is what i did so far, I don't know how to show the stone position.
Thanks